# error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’

Tags: c

I wanted to use this code to compile and run through a simple breath first search algorithm but i am having this error message on all of the addVertex and addEdge function.

not sure what is going on.

main.c:120:14: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before 'S'
    addVertex('S');   // 0

here is the full C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX 5

struct Vertex {
   char label;
   bool visited;
};

//stack variables

int stack[MAX]; 
int top = -1; 

//graph variables

//array of vertices
struct Vertex* lstVertices[MAX];

//adjacency matrix
int adjMatrix[MAX][MAX];

//vertex count
int vertexCount = 0;

//stack functions

void push(int item) { 
   stack[++top] = item; 
} 

int pop() { 
   return stack[top--]; 
} 

int peek() {
   return stack[top];
}

bool isStackEmpty() {
   return top == -1;
}

//graph functions

//add vertex to the vertex list
void addVertex(char label) {
   struct Vertex* vertex = (struct Vertex*) malloc(sizeof(struct Vertex));
   vertex->label = label;  
   vertex->visited = false;     
   lstVertices[vertexCount++] = vertex;
}

//add edge to edge array
void addEdge(int start,int end) {
   adjMatrix[start][end] = 1;
   adjMatrix[end][start] = 1;
}

//display the vertex
void displayVertex(int vertexIndex) {
   printf("%c ",lstVertices[vertexIndex]->label);
}       

//get the adjacent unvisited vertex
int getAdjUnvisitedVertex(int vertexIndex) {
   int i;

   for(i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
      if(adjMatrix[vertexIndex][i] == 1 && lstVertices[i]->visited == false) {
         return i;
      }
   }

   return -1;
}

void depthFirstSearch() {
   int i;

   //mark first node as visited
   lstVertices[0]->visited = true;

   //display the vertex
   displayVertex(0);   

   //push vertex index in stack
   push(0);

   while(!isStackEmpty()) {
      //get the unvisited vertex of vertex which is at top of the stack
      int unvisitedVertex = getAdjUnvisitedVertex(peek());

      //no adjacent vertex found
      if(unvisitedVertex == -1) {
         pop();
      } else {
         lstVertices[unvisitedVertex]->visited = true;
         displayVertex(unvisitedVertex);
         push(unvisitedVertex);
      }
   }

   //stack is empty, search is complete, reset the visited flag        
   for(i = 0;i < vertexCount;i++) {
      lstVertices[i]->visited = false;
   }        
}

int main() {
   int i, j;

   for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)    // set adjacency {
      for(j = 0; j < MAX; j++) // matrix to 0
         adjMatrix[i][j] = 0;
   }

   addVertex('S');   // 0
   addVertex('A');   // 1
   addVertex('B');   // 2
   addVertex('C');   // 3
   addVertex('D');   // 4

   addEdge(0, 1);    // S - A
   addEdge(0, 2);    // S - B
   addEdge(0, 3);    // S - C
   addEdge(1, 4);    // A - D
   addEdge(2, 4);    // B - D
   addEdge(3, 4);    // C - D

   printf("Depth First Search: ")
   depthFirstSearch(); 

   return 0;   
}
```

Comment: `// set adjacency {` Missed a brace

Comment: for loop before that AddVertex call is missing a `{`. This was caused by K&R style indentation here: `// set adjacency {`

Comment: And missing a semicolon near the end: `printf("Depth First Search: ")` **`;`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got two problems:
-  one `{` is behind a `//`
- one `;` is missing

```
int main() {
   int i, j;

   for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++){    // set adjacency  (problem with braces !!)
      for(j = 0; j < MAX; j++)  // matrix to 0
         adjMatrix[i][j] = 0;
   }

   addVertex('S');   // 0
   addVertex('A');   // 1
   addVertex('B');   // 2
   addVertex('C');   // 3
   addVertex('D');   // 4

   addEdge(0, 1);    // S - A
   addEdge(0, 2);    // S - B
   addEdge(0, 3);    // S - C
   addEdge(1, 4);    // A - D
   addEdge(2, 4);    // B - D
   addEdge(3, 4);    // C - D

   printf("Depth First Search: ");    //here ; is missing
   depthFirstSearch(); 

   return 0;   
}
```